# TraefIk Forward Auth Request URI

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication

I am using Traefik's Foward Auth middleware to authenticate my requests.

The auth server is hosted at `http://localhost/auth`
The requests that I want to authenticate are from `http://rooms.localhost/:roomId`

For example, `http://rooms.localhost/ed455783-1502-4c9e-a403-28e621d77fb4?token=qwerty` is my request URL. Now the URL is forwarded to the auth server for authentication. But at the auth server, I am not able to see the requested URL or header like X-Forwarded-URI.

The headers which I can see are

```
{
host: 'localhost',
'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.3',
 accept: '*/*',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost',
'x-forwarded-port': '80',
'x-forwarded-prefix': '/faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495',
'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
'x-forwarded-server': 'b35a8676b5a8',
'x-real-ip': '127.0.0.1'
}
```

So how should I get the requested URI in order to access the `token`?

> Note that passing token in cookies or headers is not an option for me because the WebSocket connections are also needed to be authenticated.

Following are my traefik labels

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495-auth.forwardauth.address:   http://localhost/auth
- traefik.http.middlewares.faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes:   /faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495
- traefik.http.routers.faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495.middlewares:    faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495-stripprefix, faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495-auth
- traefik.http.routers.faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495.rule:   Host(`rooms.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/faa054d5-0fe3-435e-83cb-9b817177d495`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using

```
--entryPoints.web.address=:80 
--entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure
```

Comment: is the token in query parameter fowarded?